# Front derailleur doesn't change from grear 1 to gear 2

Tags: repair, derailleur

I have a Shinamo Tourney front derailleur that doesn't change well from gear 1 to gear 2 (I'm new to bicycles so I don't know standards, so I think I should specify that gear #1 is the smallest).
In fact, it does sometimes change, but only after a few minutes of pedaling, and it keeps making a rattling sound as it's still on gear #1, but the "command" is to get to gear #2.
The problem only holds when I change from 1 to 2, never viceversa. I think, but I am not 100% sure that the problem might be correlated with my chain falling off a while back (I don't remember the details, as in which gear I was and all that, sorry).

I'm not sure if I got to detail the problem as I should be, just because I'm new to this, but if you are willing to help and feel that I missed some information, please let me know and I will give you the information you need.

Comment: If this is a new bike, purchased from a bike shop, you should take it back for a free tuneup.  The shift cables stretch when new, and this sort of adjustment is to be expected.  If it's not a new bike or not from a bike shop, you still need to take it to a bike shop for a minor tuneup.  Many shops will do this for free, or for a very small fee.  While at the shop the mechanic can show you the "barrel adjuster" that can be used to "fine tune" the shifting.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will try, but I'm not expecting any results, because I live in a small town and we don't have anything that does bike-related servicing anywhere close. So, in case it doesn't work out, can you please tell me some terms I could google so I can sort the problem out myself? (I have a feeling it's not easy to explain in 500 words and there is no point in doing so anyway, since I can google it)

Comment: Not exactly under 500 words, but see [this Sheldon Brown article](http://sheldonbrown.com/derailer-adjustment.html).  In essence, if the derailer is not too badly out of adjustment, you adjust the "barrel adjuster" -- something on the shift cable that you screw in or out to effectively lengthen or shorten the shift cable.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't find the "barrel adjuster", what you could do is pull the cable a little bit more.

Find the bolt on the derailleur that holds the cable.
Just in case, check that if you pull the cable by hand the derailleur cage moves outwards. If so, set the derailleur to the lowest gear.

Hold the cable with pliers, and with a hex key release the bolt slightly, then pull the cable to make sure it's very tense. (It won't go too far, just a little.) Tighten the bolt again as you still hold the cable with the pliers.

Comment: And, of course, the limit screws may need adjusting.